# Trying to combine text with a whitespace in between arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine 2 strings with a whitespace in between, but I'm getting an error when one of the arguments is empty. Anyone got a clue as to how I can solve this?

```py
def combine(arg1, arg2):
    s = ''
    s = arg1.strip()+ ' ' +arg2.strip()
    return s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "default parameter values" to manage such instances as you cannot leave positional parameters empty.

So, in place of `arg2` we can use `arg2=''` to state that in case it's not changed with any argument an empty string will be it's default value.

```py
def combine(arg1, arg2=''):
    s = ''
    s = arg1.strip()+ ' ' +arg2.strip()
    return s
```

```py
>>> combine('Hello', 'World!')
'Hello World!'
>>> combine('Hello!')
'Hello! '
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is occurring due to the "return s.split" line at the bottom of the function, as that will just split it back up again. Try:

```
def combine(arg1, arg2):
  s = arg1.strip() + ' ' + arg2.strip()
  return s
```

This function will take to strings and print them together with a whitespace in-between.

Comment: unfortunately, the problem still persists after removing .split. if one of the arguments is empty i still get an error.

Comment: I think what you need is in the declaration, to make the arguments optional. For example, if you write it like "def combine(arg1=' ',arg2=' '):" then both of the arguments will default to whitespace, and will be set to that if the argument is not specified. This means that if you only put one of the arguments, the other will go to its default value, the whitespace character.

Comment: This does seem to be a possible solution, i will try testing this. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Indent it.

```
def combine(arg1, arg2):

    s = ''

    s = arg1.strip()+ ' ' +arg2.strip()

    return s
```